# Output on Powershell script not displaying properly

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that audits an imported CSV and spits out a completed version of the CSV adding columns that state if the users in the CSV are in AD and if so are they active or not.

```
#CSV file to have header of "Employee" with First and Last name in each row
Echo "CSV file to import must be in c:\temp folder location with header of "Employee""
$csvlocate = (Read-Host -Prompt "CSV File to import (enter in like filename.csv and make sure file is in c:\temp folder)")
$csvEmployees = Import-Csv -path C:\temp\$csvlocate.csv
$adUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter *

foreach ($Employee in $csvEmployees) {
    $Found = $adUsers | Where-Object { ($_.GivenName -eq $Employee.givenName) -and ($_.Surname -eq $Employee.surName) }
    if ($Found) {
        "In AD $($Employee.givenName) $($Employee.surName)."
        $Employee | Add-Member -Name InAD -Value $true -MemberType NoteProperty
        $Employee | Add-Member -Name Enabled -Value $Found.Enabled -MemberType NoteProperty
    } else {
        "Not in AD $($Employee.givenName) $($Employee.surName)."
        $Employee | Add-Member -Name InAD -Value $false -MemberType NoteProperty
        $Employee | Add-Member -Name Enabled -Value $false -MemberType NoteProperty
    }
}



$csvEmployeesNotInAd = $csvEmployees.foreach{
    $employee = @{
        'CSVName' = $_.Name
        'InAD' = $false
    }
    if ($_.Name -in $adUsers.Name) {
        $employee.InAD = $true
    }
    [pscustomobject]$employee
}



$csvEmployees | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\$csvlocate.completed.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

When the CSV spits out all I see in the Enabled column is System.Object[]. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your code could be reduced to the following:

```bash
Import-Csv $sourceCsv | ForEach-Object {
    $filter = "(&(givenName={0})(Surname={1}))" -f $_.givenName, $_.Surname
    $user   = Get-AdUser -LDAPFilter $filter
    $_.PSObject.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('InAd', [bool] $user))
    $_.PSObject.Add([psnoteproperty]::new('Enabled', [bool] $user.Enabled))
    $_
} | Export-Csv $destinationCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

The `if` / `else` conditions are not needed at all, you also don't need to query all AD Users for this comparison, this is quite inefficient, or will be in a Domain with a high amount of user objects.

**`[bool] $user`** and **`[bool] $user.Enabled`** works because if the user couldn't be found, in other words, `$user` is `$null`, by casting `[bool]` we would be getting `$false`.

Also, having a CSV with the user's **GivenName and Surname** is a terrible idea. You should be using one of these:

- **DistinguishedName**
- **objectGUID**
- **objectSid**
- **sAMAccountName**

Comment: Thank you. I ran into a bunch of errors when running what you put up there. I'm thinking I need to restart this script using your suggestions. I appreciate it!

Comment: @MatthewS for sure you need to define `$sourceCsv` and `$destinationCsv` with their corresponding paths. Aside from that, the only thing that could fail is if a value for the columns is empty or if the Csv already has columns with name `InAd` and `Enabled`

Comment: The csv only had one column with the users first and last names and nothing else.

Comment: @MatthewS then it must have 2 columns doesnt it? In your code you're using `$_.GivenName` and `$_.Surname` (that wouldn't be possible with a Csv with 1 column)

Comment: I took this from another script I and a colleague had done at a previous job and in that we did the columns like that but in this new role the csv's we can export from the systems we use will have a column with their first and last name in it.